# PDFSharp saved Document always promps the "Save changes" message after filling form fields

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfsharp

Recently I made a program where I take a pdf file and using PDFsharp fill in the form fields with required values. The code that I made works fine it writes the values just fine but the problem comes after you open the pdf and try to close it, you will get a the standard message "Do you want to save changes before closing" even thou you just opened and close the document. The code that I use looks like this:

```
        string templateDocPath = @"Original.pdf";
        using (PdfDocument myTemplate = PdfReader.Open(templateDocPath, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Modify))
        {
            PdfAcroForm form = myTemplate.AcroForm;

            if (form.Elements.ContainsKey("/NeedAppearances"))
            {
                form.Elements["/NeedAppearances"] = new PdfBoolean(true);
            }
            else
            {
                form.Elements.Add("/NeedAppearances", new PdfBoolean(true));
            }

            PdfTextField testField = (PdfTextField)(form.Fields["Name"]);
            testField.Value = new PdfString("NameTest");
            testField.ReadOnly = true;

            myTemplate.Save(@"Output.pdf");
            myTemplate.Close();
        }
```

When I was trying to solved the problem I found out that the message comes only after you add "/NeedAppearances" Element to the AcroForms. You need this element or the values you write on the document will not show. 

Googling some more I found a forum (https://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=3741) where someone asked the same question but didn't get a clear answer, the last comment mentioned that "/NeedAppearances" says to the document to generate the new values. So when you open the document  new values are generated, so you have to save them.

 I would like to know if it's true and is there a way to remove the message?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this article yesterday while I was trying to find an answer for the exact problem described in the title. I was never able to find anything from any of the Google searches I ran. However, I was able to figure out what the problem was.

The issue is that when you save the PdfDocument object, it is defaulting the PDF as version 0. You can verify this by opening the generated PDF in Notepad++ (or similar text editor) and looking at the first line. When you open the PDF, Acrobat/Reader has to format it to be able to display it since it is an outdated PDF version; thus causing the document to be changed.

The solution is to set the Version of the PdfDocument before you save (an example of this can be seen here: https://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=617). As of PDFsharp version 1.50, the highest supported version is 17 (see [PDFsharp Wiki on which PDF versions are supported](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/pdfsharpfaq.ashx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1#Which_PDF_versions_are_supported_by_PDFsharp_7)).

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Checking the file with a text editor shows "%PDF-1.6" as the first line even without setting the file version manually, even after setting to version 17 still proms the message. But still thanks I will look into it a bit more.